# hide all divs and show only the one that is clicked

Tags: jquery, list, toggle

I create 3 unorderlist with two list items in it. All contains the same classes. My problem is I don't know how to hide the `<ul>` which is already opened when 1 item is clicked. I've tried doing the code below so that I can still toggle the item but the only problem is you can open all of the item at the same time.

```
$('.click_me').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).next('.ul_lists').toggle();

           });



   <a class="click_me" href="#">Click Me></a>
   <ul class="ul_lists">
       <li><a href="#" class="list_1">Some Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="list_2">Some Item</a></li>
   </ul>


   <a class="click_me" href="#">Click Me></a>
   <ul class="ul_lists">
       <li><a href="#" class="list_1">Some Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="list_2">Some Item</a></li>
   </ul>


   <a class="click_me" href="#">Click Me></a>
   <ul class="ul_lists">
       <li><a href="#" class="list_1">Some Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="list_2">Some Item</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('.click_me').click(function(event)
{
    var display = $(this).next('.ul_lists').css( "display" );
    $( ".ul_lists" ).hide();
    $(this).next('.ul_lists').css( "display", display );
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.ul_lists').toggle();
});
```

Comment: It is closing all other items that is already opened. But the toggle is not working....

Comment: @user2310422 please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.click_me').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.ul_lists').hide();
            $(this).next('.ul_lists').show();

       });


<a class="click_me" href="#">Click Me></a>
   <ul class="ul_lists">
       <li><a href="#" class="list_1">Some Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="list_2">Some Item</a></li>
   </ul>


   <a class="click_me" href="#">Click Me></a>
   <ul class="ul_lists">
       <li><a href="#" class="list_1">Some Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="list_2">Some Item</a></li>
   </ul>


   <a class="click_me" href="#">Click Me></a>
   <ul class="ul_lists">
       <li><a href="#" class="list_1">Some Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="list_2">Some Item</a></li>
   </ul>
```

This will close all UL and then open the clicked one. Basically closing the one opened if any.

You could also use a mechanic to add a class or ID to the element opened and close that one.